# Can I restore a save file from PSN+ thats a couple of days old?

Tags: ps3, dead-island

I'm having problems with Dead Island with some trophies and DLC's and I was wondering if there was a way to restore an OLD PSN+ save file?.. It already updated my last save file :/ Does it mean it overwrote it and its lost!? D':

Answer (score 3):

The only save file you can restore is the one visible in the cloud folder. There isn't any way to restore older saves.